# Changing the colour of a template Slide using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have a created a slide template in which multiple teams will use to use to create an information sheet about their respective Process. This content is intended to be produced in a standardised way.

To make things easier I have created a sheet in which key information can be input into cells to populate elements of the template.

The issue I'm having is I want each process to have a different colour scheme. Is there a way I can set a cell to the desired font or background colour in sheets and then get the template to create in that colour? or even a colour scheme?

[image: Spreadsheet Input for template]

How do I single out certain text or text boxes of the slide to set the background colour?

[image: Example of Slide]
[Desired Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOVVZ.png)

Any help is much appreciated

```
// Add a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, including a separator and a sub-menu.
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Templates')
  .addItem('Cheat Sheet', 'createNewCase')
  .addToUi();
}

function createNewCase(input) {
  var category = input
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // get active spreadsheet
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Check to ensure script being run from 'Option 1' sheet
  if (activeSheet.getName() != "Sheet1") {
  ui.alert("Active sheet must be 'Sheet1', terminating script");
  return;
  }  

  //Get active cell
  var sourceRow = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

  // Read case variables
  var sourceProcess = activeSheet.getRange('A' + sourceRow).getValue();
  var sourceName1 = activeSheet.getRange('B' + sourceRow).getValue();
  var sourceName2 = activeSheet.getRange('C' + sourceRow).getValue();
  var sourceTeam = activeSheet.getRange('D' + sourceRow).getValue();
  var sourcePurpose = activeSheet.getRange('E' + sourceRow).getValue();
  var sourceDef = activeSheet.getRange('F' + sourceRow).getValue();
  var sourceColor = activeSheet.getRange('G' + sourceRow).getFontColor();

  // Message prompt
  var userChoice = ui.alert("You are about to generate a Cheat Sheet template for " + sourceProcess +"\n\nDo you wish to continue?\n\n",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (userChoice == ui.Button.NO) {
  ui.alert("Terminating script");
  return;
  } 

  //Set case document filename
  var newFilename = sourceProcess + "Process Cheat Sheet"

  //Get template folder
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1MCQn9_oiaaUt4_dNzr2EoDWkUGsYOH-O");

  // Get case Template document
  var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("1cmm1ifvfRv7omGVmRhD0zunCngBcIY_qo2jpCA_sHV4"); 
  var caseDocument = docTemplate.makeCopy(newFilename);

  var caseDocumentID = caseDocument.getId();
  var caseSlide = SlidesApp.openById(caseDocumentID);
  var caseName1 = caseSlide.replaceAllText("%NAME1%", sourceName1);
  var caseName2 = caseSlide.replaceAllText("%NAME2%", sourceName2);
  var caseProcess = caseSlide.replaceAllText("%PROCESS%", sourceProcess);
  var caseTeam = caseSlide.replaceAllText("%TEAM%", sourceTeam);
  var casePurpose = caseSlide.replaceAllText("%PURPOSE%", sourcePurpose);
  var caseDef = caseSlide.replaceAllText("%DEFINITION%", sourceDef);

  // Record Case Document link      
  activeSheet.getRange('H' + (sourceRow)).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + caseDocument.getUrl() + '", "Cheat Sheet Template")');
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I have edited my post hopefully you can view the images. So from column G in the Spreadsheet Input for template I have a set a cell colour which I would like to represent the colour scheme of the slide in the second image. Hope this make sense.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. I edited your question in order to display the images. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the relationship of both images. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: So I would like to use column G in the sheet (Image 1) to drive the colour of the Google slide (Image 2). At the moment I can use the sheet to drive the content and text, but not able to use it to drive the colour format of the slide.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot image the vision of the output you want, yet. If I could understand about it, I would like to think of your solution. I'm sorry for this situation.

Comment: Hi I've added another screenshot, to try and get you to understand. When generating template I would to change the colour scheme based on the cell background fill within the sheet (Column G)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. There are the methods for changing the background color of text box and the color of text using [``getFill()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getFill()) and [``getTextStyle()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#gettextstyle), respectively. But I cannot propose the modification points of your script from your provided images, yet. I'm sorry for this situation.